# network drive path for images in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

In tomcat 7 I have set the context#image.xml in tomcat/catalina/localhost folder as following

```
<Context path="/image" docBase="C:\application\images" crossContext="true"/>
```

Now this works fine as I'm able to see the images in the browser.

But what if I want the images to be displayed in the browser through tomcat from a windows network drive. say the path is \net1\applications\images ? if it possible?

I tried providing the the above mentioned network path in context.xml... but the image is not displayed. it's throwing error. What am I doing wrong? or is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried mapping the network path to a local drive (say x:) and then adding x:\application\images to the xml file above ?

Comment: First thing i tried was what you said.. after googling I found that it won't work as tomcat doesn't know the mapped network drive. So I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Well, that needs to work. Are you running the tomcat service as the same "authenticated user" as the one that you used to map the network drive ?

Comment: just to confirm.. what's the best way to check if the service is same as authenticated user? Tomcat service is started with Admin rights...I'm logged in as my personal account which also has the network path mapped to a local drive which is accessible. I'm able to access the image from a network drive if I directly put the path in browser's address bar

Comment: hey... thanks.. I got it working... your tip helped me.. Yes that was a user access issue. The service was started as admin. So I shutdown the service and started the service in my user ID and it worked fine! Thanks a lot mate..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as described [here](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2010/08/accessing-network-drive-from-apache-and.html).

The user account used for services has not network access. You must create a new user, and configure the service so that it logs on as this user.